# Is TFS 2010 really installable on Windows 7?

Tags: tfs

I read it is but I tried and it says it requires Win 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Basic" install type works just fine on Windows 7 with the RTM.

A quick look at an older [blog post](http://juliocasal.com/archive/2009/10/23/installing-team-foundation-server-2010-beta-2-on-windows-7-using-the-basic-configuration.aspx) matches the same steps I followed on my laptop with the RTM.

Comment: ok thanks. Maybe I made a confusion about what I read: TFS or Sharepoint :)

Comment: No problem.  If you want portal functionality, you can install WSS.  It is quite possible that MOSS has an OS restriction.  I am proud and happy to say that is something I do not know off of the top of my head.  ;-)

Comment: Yeah - TFS installs great on Windows 7, I've done it lots of times myself.  You don't need to install any of the pre-requisites (like IIS, SQL, WSS etc) but it *just works* for version control, work item tracking, build etc.  If you do the install after you've installed Visual Studio on the same machine then it seems to work even better (as Visual Studio will do the hard part of installing .NET 4.0 and SQL Express)

Comment: @asksuperu: you can install SharePoint 2010 on Win7, but you need to modify an installer config to override the Server check. This is not supported for production use. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx